#  Apostrophe  in “beginners guide”

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe

In the phrase *beginners guide to …*,  where should the apostrophe go?

1. Beginner**’**s Guide to […]
2. Beginners**’** Guide to […]

In my particular case, this is the title for a presentation so there are multiple beginners that are being addressed.

Comment: << Beginners guide >> and << experts guide >> with the plural-form attributive (in sound mimicking the traditional possessive forms) are becoming more commonly seen today. The comparable << working mens clubs >>, << writers guilds >>, << childrens clothing departments >> and of course << dogs homes >>  are mentioned in other threads.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your intention is to address each member of the audience directly, I suggest you prefix the phrase with an appropriate article, as in:

> A Beginner's Guide to Shoe Hurling

or

> The Beginner's Guide to Shoe Hurling

The use of the apostrophe before s seems more apt in this context.

Although:

> Beginners' Guide to Shoe Hurling

is also grammatically correct, but would make your presentation sound impersonal.

Answer (score 12):

You can argue cogently for either position:

- Beginner's Guide - this is a guide for one beginner at a time (and is probably the best choice)
- Beginners' Guide - this is a guide for all beginners at the same time.

However, normally one person is reading (one copy of) a text at a time, and therefore "Beginner's" is the more normal.  It is more likely that you will be perceived as not knowing how to handle apostrophes if you use "Beginners'".

Comment: Thanks. So in the context of a presentation given to multiple people, the second is the better choice?

Answer (score 7):

Either is correct and you'd have to choose based on context: "A beginner's guide to peg solitaire" vs "Beginners' guide to flash-mob culture".