# "A Beginner's Guide" or "Beginner's Guide"?

Tags: grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should the apostrophe go in the word “beginners” in “beginners guide”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/where-should-the-apostrophe-go-in-the-word-beginners-in-beginners-guide)

Hi,

Is "Beginner's Guide To Something" Correct?

Comment: It's not about the apostrophe, it's about the "A" or without the "A"...

Comment: please check the top answer to that question.