# photographers' club of detroit or photographers club of detroit?

Tags: possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“User's guide” vs. “users' guide”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/users-guide-vs-users-guide)

I prefer non-possessive form of the name of the club: photographers club of Detroit. Is it correct?

Comment: Capitalization would be as important as placement of apostrophes.

Answer (score 3):

No one can object to *Detroit Photographers’ Club*. A club has more than one member and that is shown by placing the apostrophe after the *s*. However, this is one instance where the apostrophe is disappearing: nothing is lost by omitting it altogether.

According to ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’, the removal of the apostrophe from 'plural nouns in phrases which express affiliation . . . is widespread in the English-speaking world' and has the imprimatur of the American Associated Press stylebook and the Australian government *Style Manual*. As the Cambridge Guide says, ‘the time spent worrying about whether it should really be *driver’s licence* or *drivers’ licence* would be better used elsewhere.’

Comment: With no evidence to back it up, I suspect Brits may be discarding that apostrophe faster than Americans. Also, in some "adjectival noun phrase" contexts, we often discard the pluralising **s** as well as the possessive apostrophe. To me, *"the Student Union building)"* sounds perfectly natural, but I don't know whether that's because I was a student, because I'm a Brit, or just because that's what everyone across the world says.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I have expanded my answer to show that the disappearance of the apostrophe in such cases is not confined to the UK.

Comment: Haha - I like that final sentence! (our old "friend" Pam Peters?). I'll leave my comment there because the more general point remains valid, even if there's no UK/US divide. I personally always ***say*** *"drivers license"* (and spell it thus), but [all four permutations do occur](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=driver+licence%2Cdrivers+licence%2Cdriver+license%2Cdrivers+license&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the word *photographers*. If it's a modifier not a pronoun then you don't need an apostrophe. In which case, I don't think you really need the plural form of it. So it should read:

> Photographer club of Detroit.

However, if the word *photographers* acts as a possessive pronoun, then you need an apostrophe.

> Photographers' club of Detroit. Or Photographer's club of Detroit.

Comment: Surely not Noah's last suggestion "...Photographer's..." - a club would almost certainly have more than one member...

Comment: @DavidR It's a strange world. I added that because I thought they might have it in Detroit :) just incase.

Answer (score -1):

Detroit photography club.
The club is about photography; not about photographers.
Sewing club, chess club, tennis club. Not tennis players club.

Answer (score -2):

I would agree on the grounds that it is a club consisting of photographers, not a club owned by photographers.

Comment: Wrong. The possessive apostrophe can indicate "association" just as much as "ownership". Eric doesn't own his friends any more than I do - but they're still *my friends* and *Eric's friends*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Quite right. A "Servicemen's Club" is to be found in many towns.