# To apostrophe or not to apostrophe

Tags: grammatical-number, punctuation, apostrophe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User’s Guide vs Users’ Guide](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/users-guide-vs-users-guide)

I am sorry if this is really obvious but I can't work out from Wikipedia if it's right to use one here. My English is terrible but I try:

> Christmas parties are the cornerstone of most (companies | company's |
>   companie's) cultures.

Could someone please set me straight?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this two ways:

> A. Christmas parties are the cornerstone of most company cultures.

In this case, *company* functions as an adjective and doesn't take an apostrophe. It doesn't matter whether you mean one or, as in this sentence, many companies because English adjectives don't take number.

> B. Christmas parties are the cornerstone of most companies' cultures.

*Companies* is the plural form of the noun *company*. It takes number. The possessive apostrophe is added after the plural morpheme (/-es/).

Comment: @RegDwighт♦: Thank you for the edit. I shouldn't use those abbreviations in answers. I have to in comments because I usually write too much. I frequently forget myself that way.