# What is the single word for a school where only boys study?

Tags: single-word-requests

A school where both boys and girls study is called co-ed (co-education)  What is the name for the school where only males study? 
(Calling it a male school seems a bit awkward)

Comment: Someone can mention "Men's colleges" also in their answer. "All-male school" is used to include adults as well.

Comment: English allows you to use more than one word to express concepts. Neat, huh?

Comment: [“Attending all-boys schools or all-girls schools rather than attending coeducational schools is significantly associated with higher average scores.”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-sex_education#cite_ref-10)

Comment: In the 1960s, in England, I went to a "mixed school" rather than to the "boys high school"; there was also a "girls high school".

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, such schools are called *boys' schools*.

> St James Senior **Boys’ School** in Ashford, TW15, offers a distinctive philosophical education ...
>
> [[St James Senior Boys' School]](http://www.stjamesschools.co.uk/seniorboys/)

It's also possible to describe such as a school as an *all-boys school,* but Brits are just as likely to say "boys' school":

> Rupert's at an all-boys school — St James Boys' School in Ashford.
> Horatio is at a certain boys' school in Harrow.

Using *all-boys* emphasises the nature of the school as a single-sex school over the simple adjective *boys'*.

Comment: So in this respect a school filled with girls would be called all-girls school? There arent any specific word for these kind?

Comment: Yes: exactly the same applies to *girls' school* and *all-girls school.*

Comment: This is the best answer. Shwetabh Shekhar, people don't usually use the wording with *all*. They usually just use *boys' schools* or *girls' schools*.

Comment: Even in an all-sex school, sometimes only the girls study. :)

Answer (score 1):

The term for the practice of teaching the two genders separetly, regardless of the gender we might be talking about is:

> ***Single-Sex Education*** or ***Single-Gender Education*** or ***Single-Sec Schooling***.
>   Source: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-sex_education)

For specific institution catering to one specific gender-

> *The Boarding School Review* uses the terms ***All-Boys*** and ***All-Girls*** to refer to as the Student Body type for single-sex institutions, [here](http://www.boardingschoolreview.com/researchschools.php).

Using the search function above, the websites of single-sex institutions shows that the websites themselves rarely use a term for that aspect of their student body - either there's no explicit mention of the school being all-boys outside of admission qualifications, or terms like "Educating Young Men since..." etc are used.

The wikipedia category for these schools in the US is simply "[Boys' Schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Boys%27_schools_by_country)" (the *all* does seem a bit redundant), and the articles themselves use a mix of ***All-Boys*** or ***Boys'*** Schools as terminology.

eg.

> - Archbishop Riordan High School is an ... **all-boys** Catholic high school.. in San Francisco.
> - Newington College is a ... day and boarding school **for boys**... in Australia
> - Ardscoil Rís is a **boys' secondary school** in ... Dublin, Ireland
> - Catholic High School (traditional Chinese: 公敎中學) ... is an **all-boys** Catholic school in Singapore.
> - Nyeri High School', also known as Nyeri High, is a **boys' boarding school** ... in Nyeri, Kenya.

Answer (score 1):

A school for boys is a ***[boys' school](http://www.theibsc.org/)*** and one for girls is a ***[girls' school](http://www.gsa.uk.com/)***, although the trend in the language, as noted in the answers to [“Boys bicycle” vs. “boy's bicycle”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87345) and [User’s/Users’/Users Group](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76593) and others, is to drop the apostrophe; thus *[boys school](http://www.landon.net/page.cfm?p=3932)*  and *[girls school](http://www.discoveryschool.org/girlsschool.html)* are increasingly common.

As coeducation is the norm for most people in most English-speaking countries, the meaning of *school for boys* or *school for girls* is also clear, though at least in North America, it would be more common to describe such an institution as an  *[all-boys school](http://www.privateschoolreview.com/state_boys_highschools/type/8/stateid/NY)* (or *[all-girls school](http://www.latimes.com/local/crime/la-me-teacher-student-20140714-story.html)*).

Answer (score 0):

Many schools for single-sex or single-gender education do not include "for Boys" or "for Girls" in their name.  Some examples include:

> - [Marmion Academy](http://marmion.org/s/1356/academy/start.aspx?gid=1&pgid=365)
> - [Eton College](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eton_College)

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-sex_education) references the single-sex or single-gender terminology in describing such schools.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that [single-sex schools are waning in the UK. In 1966, there were 2,500; in 2006, there were just 400](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/women/womens-life/10145431/What-going-to-a-girls-school-really-does-to-you.html). There's public debate at the moment because some (mainly immigrant) minority communities approve of segregation, but mainstream society and the legislature are pushing hard "to open" established single-sex schools and  up prevent new ones being set up.

So in most contexts in the UK today, *any* reference to a segregated school (by sex, religion, race) is likely to be somewhat pejorative/disparaging. But 50 years ago when I went to the local State-run ***boys' school*** (which was just down the road from the affiliated ***girls' school***), those were perfectly normal ways to refer to what were at the time perfectly normal schools. Today it simply wouldn't be possible to use either term without risking unwanted connotations being perceived.

Comment: I'm not clear why you say it 'would not be possible to use either term without risking unwanted connotations being perceived'. My own children (now in their thirties) went to two of the remaining grammar schools, both of which were state-run - one a 'boys' school' and one a 'girls' school'. The schools concerned remain single-sex today.  What, in your view, should they be called?

Comment: @WS2: Like I said, mine was a *boy's school* back in the day, and that carried no significant connotations beyond the literal meaning. But it's not surprising to me that your kids went to single-sex ***grammar*** schools. Even a couple of decades ago there were very few "mainstream" single-sex schools left - by the present day, if you say your daughter goes to a *girls' school* people are likely to make assumptions (you went to some trouble to get her into a single-sex school, either for cultural / religious reasons or some "indirectly academic" reason such as *local girls' grammar school*).

Comment: The only form of grammar school education available in the town where we live, both twenty years ago and now, is single-sex. We, as parents went to no particular 'trouble' to get our children in, other than drive them to the place where the examination was held. And we did not especially favour grammar-school education. It was simply that it was there! A girl we fostered, went to a single-sex comprehensive. It remains today as does the single-sex boys' affiliated school. And those two comprehensives record stunning performance results, albeit admittedly in a well-to-do middle class area.

Comment: @WS2: That was partly why I specifically said ***unwanted** connotations*. It might well be that in your specific case the kids went to those schools "because they were there", and the fact of them being single-sex establishments was incidental. But as the years roll by it becomes increasingly less likely that there would be no "backstory" to the statement *"Our daughter attends the local girls' school"*. Incidentally, *my* daughter (now in her twenties) attended her local grammar school, but it stopped being single-sex decades ago.

Comment: If single-sex schools are waning, does that mean that bisexual schools are waxing?  Or did you just leave out a *k*? :)

Comment: Single-sex education for girls went through a brief renaissance a few years ago following some research which seemed to show that girls did better in maths and science with no boys around. But the Independent (private) sector, with schools desperate to sustain numbers on the roll and hence their incomes have increasingly welcomed pupils of either sex.

Comment: @WS2: It's true private schools [were hit by the credit crunch](http://www.theguardian.com/education/2012/apr/26/private-school-pupil-numbers-rise), but over the longer term, their rolls have steadily increased since [the low point of the mid-70s](http://cee.lse.ac.uk/ceedps/ceedp115.pdf) (graph, p27). They're not exactly "desperate to sustain numbers".

Answer (score 0):

*Seminary* had, until about 1900, a meaning of *school for boys*. The equivalent for girls, as the three little maids told us, was *a ladies seminary*.

Comment: Could you please some documentation for that? I haven’t found any references for it. Thanks.