# First year's conference or first years' conference?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User’s Guide vs Users’ Guide](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/users-guide-vs-users-guide)

As in, a conference that is for people in their first year of, say, University.

Comment: We have a [blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/11/much-ado-about-possessive-apostrophes/) that answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

Those in their first year at a university are commonly called [*first years*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman). Thus, their conference would be *first years' conference*.

Answer (score 0):

The conference is held annually, so there's only one first year for a year.
You should use "first year's".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a helpful explanation that you might give the OP or a reference you might cite?