# "Woman students" OR "Women students" - which one is correct?

Tags: word-usage

If I mean to say that many students who were also women smoked cigarettes, but do not wish to use "female students," which of the following would be correct to say:

a) Many **woman students** smoked cigarettes

OR

b) Many **women students** smoked cigarettes

I have read all the related posts - they are all helpful but doesn't answer my specific question. As a general rule, the first noun is often singular as in "girl students" and not "girls students" but there are exceptions to this rule, for instance, "women leaders." In fact, I have seen both "woman presidents" and "women presidents" being used frequently.

Could someone, please explain me, any rule there might be for pluralizing compound nouns where both the head noun or attributive noun and the noun it modifies are countable (Please note that I don't mean 'student' here as a collective noun for a body of students).

Comment: The expression female students is, somehow, preferable to me.

Comment: You know what's weird? "Women students" sounds fine to me, as do the dictionary examples of "women voters" and "women athletes". But imagine saying "men students", "men voters" or "men athletes". I just realized this. Hmm, that is odd. Well to me it is.

Comment: related: [Which form should be used for “student union”: singular, plural, possessive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200551/which-form-should-be-used-for-student-union-singular-plural-possessive)

Comment: also related: [“woman” or “women” as a stand-in for the adjective “female”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161590/woman-or-women-as-a-stand-in-for-the-adjective-female/161619#161619) (closed) and also [Is it correct to say “I write children books” (not possessive case)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case)

Comment: Why don't you want to use "female students"? Are you wanting to indicate adult female students specifically?

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, precisely. Also because it's academic (social science) writing where women is preferred over female.

Comment: @Ritam What source are you using that says "women is preferred over female" even in academic writing? I would guess that it was referring to use as a noun, e.g. "women smoking cigarettes",  whereas "female" is fine or even preferred as an adjective, e.g. "female students smoking cigarettes."

Comment: @KamilDrakari AP Style (not academic) suggests avoiding male/female whenever possible.

Comment: @AzorAhai As far as I can tell, [this tweet](https://twitter.com/APStylebook/status/634722377365094400) is from the official twitter account of the AP Stylebook, and does not agree with that (unless it has changed since then).

Comment: @KamilDrakari I think mine is from 2014, so I guess they may have changed it.

Comment: @Zebrafish: it's not just you; it's weird for me, too especially once I think about it.  I think might be related to why "co-ed" = "female college student" bothers me: it only makes sense if the default assumption was male.  Or reinforces that "letting" women be students is a new / special thing.  But that doesn't seem to fit this case.  Let's look at commonly gender-biased roles: "women nurses" vs. "men nurses".  Yeah both of those sound weird (maybe because nurses take care of people who can be male/female?)  "men secretaries"?  I think that's extra weird, but "male secretaries" is fine.

Answer (score 6):

The generally accepted rule is that when one noun that is semantically plural qualifies a following noun, whether singular or plural then it is in the singular according to this pattern: it is compulsory if the plural is formed by adding an -s and optional otherwise.

It does not seem to matter in what way the first is qualifying the second - it could be a question of whether the soldiers ARE women or girls, or of whether the fertilizer is FOR cacti or orchids.

The attached pictures show how we can use singular and plural together where any logic would say we should use one or the other.

[image: Orchid compost] [image: Cacti compost]

[image: Teeth and gums]

This explains why there is little argument on this site about girl/girls, but there is lots of argument about woman/women. Because it is optional, there will always be some who say one or the other is correct, and some situations where one or the other is more common.

I have seen this rule in a big old English grammar but I regret I do not have the reference at present.

I have never seen an explanation, but the one that seems obvious to me is that *women soldiers* is unambiguous, but *girls soldiers* could be confused with *girl's soldiers* [image: Girl's soldiers]

Comment: Your examples are fundamentally different than what the question is asking about - "orchid compost" means "compost for/of [an] orchid", but you can't say the same about "woman/women students". I'm still trying to figure out which part of the Listerine image I should be looking at.

Comment: @notthatguy You should be looking at the bit that says *TEETH & GUM* even though you have more than one gum as well as more then one tooth.

Comment: @notthatguy I agree they they are semantically different and that different rules of grammar *could* apply but it appears they don't. I cannot find any primary or secondary evidence that it matters how one noun is qualifying the other. In fact I think that my evidence about fertilizer and teeth, combined with the original question and the conflicting answers show that the same dichotomy exists in both situations.

Comment: What is the relevance of the last image?

Comment: @azorahal These are *girl's soldiers* which is what people might hear if you said *girls soldiers* instead of *girl soldiers*.

Comment: None of the provided images seem to have any relevance to the question. "Orchid compost" is meant to imply "compost for orchids", not "compost comprised of orchids" (and the same for "cacti compost"). The application of "teeth & gum" doesn't seem to have anything to do with it, and in fact just looks like two conflicting cases of whether or not to quality "defense" with a plural noun (which I'd argue against). As for the last image, there aren't any examples of a noun being qualified by a plural noun (or, indeed, another noun at all), so I couldn't begin to guess what that is about.

Comment: @abion47 I have modified my answer in response to your comment. I don't think it makes any difference in what way the first noun is qualifying the second, or indeed if the second is singular or plural. Of course if there is any evidence that different rules apply in the different circumstances that would be significant, but that is not my experience.

Answer (score -4):

The only correct form is '***women students***'.

There must be the number correspondence in this compound.

According to 
https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect2&info0=2.16:

'' ***Plurals of compound terms***

In forming the plurals of compound terms, pluralize the significant word. If both words are of equal significance, pluralize both. Pluralize the last one if no one word is significant in itself:

men drivers

women writers''.

See some examples from Reverso.context.net:

// The following table indicates the courses preferred by ***men*** and ***women students***.

// In recent years, ***women students*** have shown a distinct preference for subjects in the arts and in communication sciences and techniques.

// These are intended to prepare ***women*** ***students*** for careers in the public sector.

There's also an alternative to say 'female students'.
Here's an example from Reverso.context.net:

The occupation authorities have expelled and deported the ***male*** and ***female*** ***students*** from the West Bank and the Gaza Strip studying at university in Jerusalem.

Comment: It's *child workers* and not *children workers*. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=child+workers%2C+children+workers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchild%20workers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchildren%20workers%3B%2Cc0). So despite the fact that *women students* is the usual form, the website that you found gives advice that is wrong in general.

Comment: For another usage, also see *[Gaudy Night](https://books.google.com/books?id=pcLTJYnKDdEC&lpg=PT214&ots=9ojYyAhDIL&dq=Dorothy%20L.%20Sayers%20There%20are%20much%20better%20ways%20of%20enjoying%20Oxford%20than%20fooling%20round..with%20the%20women%20students.&pg=PT214#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Dorothy L. Sayers: "There are much better ways of enjoying Oxford than fooling round at midnight with the women students."

Comment: @user307254 Thanks, you answered my question but then why do we say 'girl students,' when, like women students, both words are of equal significance? Is it because, as Peter Shor mentions above, it pluralizes with an 's'?

Comment: The standard form is 'doubled plurals'.

Comment: Of course, the language is developing. There appear different variants of word forms.  Which is correct' is the question of time.

Comment: Here's another example from Reverso.context.net:  ''Support programmes for girls students with learning difficulties''.

Comment: The website referenced in this answer cites *courts-martial* and claims it is the more important word that takes the -s. This is indirectly correct. The important word is the noun, for example, *court*. That is why it takes an -s. The *martial*  is an adjective. It happens to be after the noun as the phrase is of French origin because the Normans introduced much of our legal terminology. As it is a bilingual English-French website they should understand the grammar of [*cour martiale*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cour_martiale).