# Help...is it "Consumer's Needs" or "Consumers' needs" ? or "Consumers Needs"?

Tags: possessives

I am doing a presentation for a packaged goods company...is it "Consumer's Changing Needs" or "Consumers' Changing Needs"  or "Consumers Changing Needs" ?
Context:  It is for a slide headline that is referring to "consumers" and category information.

Need answer asap if possible...thank you!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [User’s Guide vs Users’ Guide](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/user-s-guide-vs-users-guide)

Comment: This is not so much a duplicate as lacking signs of research.

Answer (score 2):

It should be "Consumers' Changing Needs".

Comment: As it happens, every single one of the 24 written instances of [***the** consumers' changing needs*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+Consumers+Changing+Needs%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22the+Consumers+Changing+Needs%22&tbm=bks&start=20) has the possessive *after* the plural. But I think the fact of that definite article being there strongly argues in favour of singular ***the consumer***...

Comment: ...there are after all a claimed 6620 written instances of [*the changing needs of **the consumer***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+changing+needs+of+the+consumer%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but less than a quarter of that number for plural [*the changing needs of the **consumers***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+changing+needs+of+the+consumers%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). So it depends on context and the writer's intention as much as anything - there's not really any concept of "it should be..."

Comment: @FF Quite right. And anyway, it should be 'The changing needs of the consumer'.