# Student vs Students'

Tags: word-usage

Question: Is correct to denominate a group formed by students as:

"Optics Students' Group"

or do we need to call it:

"Optics Student Group"

so that "Student" is regarded as the type of element of the group instead of the group ownership?

Comment: This is a dup of [User’s Guide vs Users’ Guide](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/user-s-guide-vs-users-guide)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm not sure about that.  This is the distinction between the Unicycling Student Group and the Unicycling Students' Group, without mention of the Unicycling Student's Group.

Comment: @JHCL: As it happens, there's no mention of a ***Unicycling Users(') Guide*** in Google Books. But how would that differ from a [***Recycling Users(') Guide***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22recycling+users+guide%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)?

Comment: The difference lies in the absence of a putative 'Recycling User Guide', ie a User Guide regarding Recycling.  I don't know how many Student Groups there are at this establishment, but the answer below from @OlegTikhonov raises the question.

Comment: It's three nouns in a row, which has disadvantages. ‘Group for optics students ‘ or ‘Student group for optics‘ have very different meanings. Which one works best?

Answer (score 1):

If it is dedicated to and formed by students of optics we would write: "optics students' group" just the way we are inclined to using 'boys' school', 'girls' hostel' or 'postgraduate women's residency'.

However, when the intention is to regard students as one of the comprising elements (not consisting of students only)--"Optics Student Group", "Optics Physician Group" or "Optics Professor Group" would work fine. The point is that we may use plural form of the subject proper in these three compound nouns but no "'s"  because possessive case means possession/ ownership. THE GROUP/CLASS BECOMES POSSESSED!!

Answer (score 0):

I would favour the latter, since I think that the 'Student Group' is the noun, and the subject of that sentence, and 'Optics' is a 'noun-as-adjective'

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm

Comment: This may be true if it is a group open to all students. If, on the other hand,  it's a Group for Students of Optics, it should be The Optics Students' Group.

Answer (score 0):

To me:

- `Optic Students' Group` implies the group belonging to Optic Students. However it could be a group belonging to students which includes professors.
- `Optics Student Group` implies the Optics group for Students as contrasted with, say, the Optics group for professors. However, it does not necessarily imply that all of the students in the group are optics students.

Neither of those is exclusive, but the latter seems to better imply the composition.