# which is better usage for this plural: sheriff's offices or sheriffs' offices

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

I am writing about a dozen different offices headed by locally elected sheriffs. There are other 'offices' in the story, so at least a couple of times I'll have to use the full phrase. In your view, is it better to leave the singular *sheriff's* and the plural *offices*? Or make both parts plural: sheriffs' offices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User’s Guide vs Users’ Guide](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/user-s-guide-vs-users-guide)

Comment: ...apparently [most people still include an apostrophe](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sheriff+offices%2Csheriffs+offices%2Csheriff%27s+offices%2Csheriffs%27+offices&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csheriff%20offices%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csheriffs%20offices%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csheriff%20%27s%20offices%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csheriffs%20%27%20offices%3B%2Cc0) in this context (usually ***after*** pluralised ***sheriffs***, where singular might imply *one* sheriff has multiple offices). But I wouldn't bother with an apostrophe at all myself.

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one sheriff then it would be sheriffs' offices. It all depends on the number of sheriffs.