# Lady's Ladies' or ladies

Tags: grammaticality

This has puzzled me for some time.  What is the possessive plural for of lady?

The lady's shoes?
The ladies' shoes?

Also, which for of lady do you use when addressing more than one female?

Good morning Ladies
or
Good morning Lady's?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User’s Guide vs Users’ Guide](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/user-s-guide-vs-users-guide)

Comment: In English an apostrophe is almost never used to pluralize a word.  The only exceptions are single letters, as in, "I have a hard time telling your q's apart from your g's" and sometimes in abbreviations, as in, "I have seven Ph.D.'s" People (even native English speakers) do erroneously use apostrophes to make words plural, but you should not follow suit.

Answer (score 4):

The plural possessive is "ladies'." "Lady" is singular, so if you were referring solely to one woman's shoes, it would be "the lady's shoes."

As for your second question, I'm assuming you're referring to a group of women in your salutation of them, so it would be "Good morning, ladies." And as you're addressing them directly, the comma preceding "ladies" is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

plural: ladies

possessive plural: ladies'

so:

> "The ladies' shoes"

and

> "Good morning, ladies"

Answer (score 0):

> The lady's shoes.

This refers to shoes owned by a lady.

> The ladies' shoes.

This refers to shoes owned by several ladies.