# Do I need an apostrophe in "These trees’ roots"?

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe, saxon-genitive

Do I need an apostrophe in "These trees’ roots"?

For example,

"Wow!!! These trees' roots are so long!"

In this example the speaker can see both roots and the trees themselves.

I looked at this question:  [Apostrophe  in “beginners guide”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/apostrophe-in-beginners-guide) but there they are discussing the case when an apostrophe is added to a person or persons (beginners), while in my case it's *trees*. Can I just drop the apostrophe in my case? (You can't drop it in case with the *Beginner's Guide*, can you?)

Comment: So there are multiple trees, and you're referring to all of their roots in general?

Comment: I suggest you look at [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/where-should-the-apostrophe-go-in-the-word-beginners-in-beginners-guide): it talks about when you need the apostrophe, and what it means.

Comment: "So there are multiple trees, and you're referring to all of their roots in general?" - Yes

Comment: "I suggest you look at this question..." - Thanks, but there they are discussing the case when apostrophe is added to a person or persons (beginners), while in my case it's trees. I though it was a different case.

Comment: This is a question of where the apostrophe goes when adding the possessive to a singular (tree, beginner) or a plural (trees, beginners). Both "tree" and "beginner" are nouns, so they actually follow the same rules.

Comment: Regardless of whether the noun denotes a person or inanimate object?

Comment: Yes. Even if the noun is a proper noun (eg. Marissa), the rules for possessive form are the same. Trees, people, cats, rocks--all of them share the rules for possession in English.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you confused because "these" is an indication of possession already? Or are you unsure of where to position an apostrophe with a plural noun to indicate possession?

Comment: Can I just drop the apostrophe in my case? (You can't drop it in case with the Beginner's Guide, can you?)

Comment: @Kitḫ - I know where to position it, but I am not sure if in my case I really need an apostrophe at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the main focus of the question is where to place the possessive apostrophe then the answers posted by Caleb and Daniel are absolutely correct, the apostrophe is placed after the suffix "s" when the possessor is plural; e.g. *the cars' wheels*, *the dogs' dinner*, *the boys' teachers* etc.

But I suggest that the original sentence be rephrased, and the OP choose the singular adjunct noun over the plural one.

1. One tree and its roots:

> Look at these **tree roots**.

The expression "tree roots" is like an open [compound noun](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound.htm), and the word ‘tree‘ is the [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). The possessive apostrophe in "tree roots” is unnecessary, similarly it is not required in other open compound nouns such as  “computer chips”, “army rations”, and “bank clerk(s)”. But what if there is more than one tree? Rephrase it.

2. Multiple trees and their roots:

> Look at the roots **of** *those* trees.

Because the possessive apostrophe is inaudible in "the trees’ roots", "the cars’ wheels”, “the dogs’ dinner” and “the boys’ teachers” the listener might infer the speaker is referring to a single possessor; i.e. a tree, a car, a dog and a boy. Say the examples out aloud, and your brain will interpret as the roots belonging to a single tree, the wheels of a single car, the dinner belonging to a dog  and the teachers of a school boy.

I am also of the opinion that the determiner ***those*** is preferable, as I imagine someone pointing to the roots of different trees on the ground.In the case where the speaker is crouched next to the roots then saying "these roots" will come more spontaneously.

Comment: Covered at [Attributive or possessive noun ... _the Dell company's staff_ or _the Dell company staff_?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114531/attributive-or-possessive-noun-the-dell-companys-staff-or-the-dell-company-st)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need the apostrophe. `-s'` denotes possession of some thing or things by multiple owners. The roots belong to the trees; the trees own the roots. Therefore, the roots are the trees' roots.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need the apostrophe, and you need it right where it is: make sure that the apostrophe is after the "s", not before.

*-s'* is the possessive ending for plural nouns (e.g. *trees* becomes *trees'*), while *-'s* is the possessive ending for singular nouns (e.g. *tree* becomes *tree's*).

Hence, *The roots **of these trees*** becomes *These trees' roots*.

And *The roots **of this tree*** becomes *This tree's roots*.

Comment: Or, of course, *These tree roots* for both cases.