# Attributive or Possessive noun: the Dell Company's staff. or the Dell Company staff?

Tags: nouns, possessives, apostrophe

In the following is it better to use a possessive noun with an apostrophe or an attributive noun without an apostrophe?

> The following list details the assumptions that have been made in
>   conjunction with the *Dell Company’s* staff.

Or

> The following list details the assumptions that have been made in
>   conjunction with the *Dell Company* staff.

Assume *Company* is the name of a company, such as Dell.

Answer (score 2):

Some companies have a style guide that specifies that the company name should not have any such additions.

So if in doubt, you should use the form *without* the apostrophe.

This also remains correct in cases where the name is foreign, and possessive forms might be constructed in a different way.

Comment: Company staff, school students, community representatives - apostrophe could be avoided here.