# When does one use an apostrophe?

Tags: apostrophe

- Student's exchange
- Family pride

For the above examples, I want to understand why the apostrophe is or isn't used? How does one determine this?

Comment: Students' exchange; family pride.

Comment: @Ricky Yes, why so? what is the formula?

Comment: Scott describes the logic for this in the answer below. As for family pride, the word "family" here is really an adjective in disguise: it substitutes for "familial," which is archaic.

Comment: Please search this forum for questions with the word "apostrophe". You will find dozens, all with good suggestions, explanations and rules. Voting to close.

Comment: better yet, search in ELL Stack Exchange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attributive or Possessive noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114531/attributive-or-possessive-noun)

Comment: For starters, there must be an apostrophe in *don't*. Do not move to more advanced rules until you've memorized that basic one.

Answer (score 1):

Possession: Use an apostrophe to indicate that the noun to which the apostrophe is appended is the owner or possessor of the following noun or noun phrase.

"The student's union" is appropriate if the union is a thing owned by a single student to whom you're referring.

"The students' union" would indicate a union belonging to many students.

If the use is descriptive but not indicating possession or ownership, no apostrophe is used. Thus we could speak of "the students list" (a list of students, but not a list possessed by a student).

Here's a somewhat contrived example using all three:

"The first student's students list was more complete than the next two students' students lists."

Contraction: use an apostrophe to indicate omission of letters, as in "can not" -> "can't", etc.

Comment: Hello, Scott. Would that it were so simple! Some people become apoplectic at the thought that the words mens, childrens might be considered acceptable, but most working mens clubs use the former rather than the apostrophised version. Writers' guilds vie with writers guilds. (Institutional) dogs homes and dogs' homes exist. And when it comes to companies like Lloyds and Lloyd's, and places named after, for example, St James ... but all this has been covered here before.

Comment: Those are all consistent. "Writers guild" or "mens club" are like the "vegetables section" of the supermarket. It isn't owned by vegetables, it's where vegetables are found.

Comment: No they're not.  _St James Park_ in Exeter contrasts with _St James's Park_ in London and _St James' Park_ in Newcastle. _Redbud Writers Guild_ contrasts with _The Long Island Writers' Guild_. _Whitworth Working Mens Club_ contrasts with _Houldsworth Working Men's Club_. Another example: _Manchester Dogs Home_ contrasts with _Manchester & Cheshire Dogs' Home_.  Usage is _inconsistent_; you're trotting out a style recommendation as though it were to be found in CGEL. And you need to say _where_ you found it, if it's a quote; if not, you need to cite an accepted guide recommending this practice.

Comment: Yes, the usage of plural and possessive adjectives is inconsistent. I mean all of your examples are consistent with the rule that an apostrophe indicates possession (except when it indicates contraction, which seemed tangential to the specific question and example).

Comment: Wrong again. Dogs don't own the Manchester & Cheshire Dogs' Home. St James' Park and St James's Park both exist. I hadn't spelled these out, but I pointed to them as examples.

Comment: Similarly, we refer to, e.g., "John's sisters" without meaning to imply that John actually owns his sisters. Your "Dogs' Home" example looks like a possessive determiner to me. They're all considered possessives grammatically, without implying ownership in a literal sense.

Comment: So you admit that 'the rule that an apostrophe indicates possession' isn't a rule at all. 'Possession' means ownership {[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/possession)}. The word is not used to refer to the grammatical usage.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_(linguistics) has a good breakdown.

Comment: In the light of which I've retracted the downvote. But I'd say we've really got to specify if we're using that rare sense, even on ELU. However, though I'd use "We bought the children's clothes at the childrens clothing department at Herods / Herod's" (up to them how they want their name) myself, it's not a practice accepted by everyone; 'If the use is descriptive but not indicating possession or ownership, no apostrophe is used. Thus we ...' sounds very authoritarian, and isn't a 'rule' in English but rather a style recommendation. Is the above a quote (in which case it needs attributing)?