# "children's literature" or "children literature"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I am always confused where to use a "possessive apostrophe".

From what I found on the internet it seems to me that children's literature is correct. What about garden chair? In my eyes it's the same. Garden is describing what kind of chair it is. Children is also describing what kind of literature I have in my mind.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: Inanimate things don't possess other things, they can only modify them.

Comment: @Ricky I don't understand. So what about garden chair?

Comment: Does garden chair, in your example, mean "a chair made of garden" or "a chair in the garden" or "a chair for use with a garden" or "a chair for use by a garden" or something else? Normally, it would mean "a chair used in the garden", so "garden" is an adjective, not a possessive.

Comment: @Davo so children literature means literature for children. And children's literature means literature owned by children?

Comment: @Radek: Saying *children literature* primarily means you're not a native speaker. Please consider using [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: well, I'm not. So do you want me to create new question over there? PS. I read your comment saying "General Reference - children is never used adjectivally, as could be established by consulting any dictionary."

Comment: The particular example children's books / childrens books (and the debate over whether the latter should nowadays be considered correct) has been [covered on ELU before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case) 'Working mens club' must be considered idiomatic. // The general ['when to use a possessive construction, when to use an attributive noun'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114531/attributive-or-possessive-noun) debate has also been covered.

Comment: @Radek: I don't think ELL even *existed* when I posted that comment over 4 years ago when I closevoted citing "General Reference". In actual fact, your specific question here was asked (and well-received) on ELL some years ago. Imho it was also *well-answered* there, but it's worth noting there's a prominent comment on the ELL question linking back to the closed one here.

Comment: You are asking why, if chicken soup is made of chicken, cat food is not made of cats.

Comment: @Radek: Garden chairs don't have souls. Children have souls. Did I use the word "inanimate"? I believe I did! Think about it. Seriously.

Comment: It might be wholly true that the chair which belongs in the garden can’t be ‘the garden’s chair’ but Davo, are you really insisting the edges of the property can’t be ‘the garden’s boundary’ or that ‘this garden’s colours’ can’t be compared to ‘that garden’s (whatever else)’?