# singular adjective versus plural possessive

Tags: grammar, differences

Dynamics which are typical of (or can be found in) news websites or the life which is typical of schools may thoeretically be described by either possessive constructs such as ***schools' life*** or ***news websites' dynamics***, or by the singular noun and adjective ***school life***, ***news website dynamics***. 
Do both forms have the same meaning? Is one of them better than the other (in general or in particular cases)? 
My question (unlike [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114531/attributive-or-possessive-noun)) is not about firm names, but rather about
***plural*** nouns such as "websites", "working places". Should I always use the singular attributive, as in "working place dynamics", "news website dynamics", or "site operators", even while meaning multiple working places or websites?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attributive or Possessive noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114531/attributive-or-possessive-noun), though there's a better comparison I can't find. You'd probably use 'school life' normally, but 'the life of the school' if you wanted to sound a little less impersonal. The Saxon genitive could be used to highlight the specific school or websites but would usually look a little odd.

Comment: Ah, [Why do we say "a hotel room" and not "a hotel's room"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159545/why-do-we-say-a-hotel-room-and-not-a-hotels-room/159560#159560) is worth looking at.

Comment: To me it seems obvious and we shouldn't need to read the details. "Singular adjective versus plural possessive" will never be more reasonable than women's knees v men's shoulder-blades.