# Possessive apostrophe regarding the term 'Logistics'

Tags: grammar, british-english, possessives, apostrophe

Just wanted to ask if the word 'logistics' would have a possessive apostrophe in the following sentence.

> Halal logistics services are needed to guarantee halal products and maintain halal product integrity.

Comment: No. The services don't belong to logistics.

Comment: So it is correct the way it is? It shouldn't be 'Halal logistic services', right? Logistic would be an incorrect word here, right?

Comment: @Ibtesam Kate has already given you a direct answer and a clear explanation.

Comment: I was confused if replacing logistics with logistic here would be correct.

Comment: _Logistics_ is a noun with only a plural form, like _mathematics_. The adjective _logistic_ apparently exists, but I think the noun is much more commonly used in this sort of context.

Comment: Got it. Thank you, Kate!

Comment: When the actual name of the company is clarified, this becomes a duplicate of [attributive or possessive noun: the Dell company's staff or the Dell company staff](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114531/attributive-or-possessive-noun-the-dell-companys-staff-or-the-dell-company-st0.)

Answer (score 1):

It might be necessary if you were talking about a company called Halal Logistics Services but in this case you appear to be talking generally about logistics services which operate to Halal standards.

For instance you might have three companies called, say, Medina Food Transport, Halal Logistics Services and Ethical Transport Solutions all of which could be described as Halal logistics services if they complied with the requirements. In advertising for the first of these you might say

> Medina Food Transport's storage, handling and vehicle maintenance procedures are designed to ensure that the Halal status of the food we transport is never compromised.

and the posessive apostrophe s at the end of the name would be necessary.

However in writing generally about Halal logistics services (note the lower case 'l' and 's' becasue 'Halal logistics services' is not part of a Proper Noun but only a description of a class of logistics services) the posessive is not only not required, it is inappropriate. I have continued to capitalise Halal because it is a set of religious requirements deserving of respect, I don't know whether this is standard practice or not. If it isn't then Halal would be written with a lowercase 'h' as well unless it was part of a company name.

Comment: Thank you, BoldBen. Your answer makes it very clear, and yes, it is not a company name. It has been used generally.