# Members’ Benefits vs Member’s Benefits

Tags: grammatical-number, british-english, possessives, apostrophe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should the apostrophe go in the word “beginners” in “beginners guide”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/where-should-the-apostrophe-go-in-the-word-beginners-in-beginners-guide)

I’m currently developing a site which has a membership scheme which you pay to sign up for. To encourage people to do this, there is a page that highlights the benefits of becoming a member.

They want this page to be called *Member’s Benefits*.

Should the apostrophe come before the *s*, or after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the benfits apply to all members, then there there isn't much of a case against *Members' Benefits*. However, the apostrophe seems to be disappearing in cases like this and *Members Benefits* is defensible on the grounds that *Members* functions as an attributive adjective (as would *Member* in *Member Benefits*).